# Please explain this method

Tags: ruby, inject, splat

I have a question regarding the stars in this method:

```
def multiplies_array(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(1, :*)
end
```

What is the meaning of the star in the argument list (`*numbers`)?
And what is the meaning of the star after the colon (`1, :*`)?

Comment: First one is a "splat operator", google it. Second one is a regular symbol (read documentation on `Enumerable#inject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first star is the splat operator. In this case it "collects" all parameters given to `multiplies_array` into a single Array.

Calling it like this with four parameters...

```
multiplies_array 1, 2, 3, 4
```

... gives you a single array with four elements in the method.

This is equivalent to:

```
def multiplies_array(numbers) # Without splat operator
end 

multiplies_array [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The second star is a little confusing. Here the the multiplication operator is meant:

The `:` denotes a symbol. All `Enumerable` methods allow passing a symbol as a shortcut. It means: "Call the method with this name".

In other words the `*` method is applied to each item in the numbers array. Without the symbol shortcut that line would look like:

```
numbers.inject(1) { |result, number| result * number) }
```

I hope this sheds a little light on all that Ruby magic :)

Comment: another little question.

    unless %w(the and over).include?(string[index])

what is %w ?

Comment: @JohnOggy post it as a different question. What is `%w`?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [inject.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

It "combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation, specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator."

So, the `:*` is specifying the multiplication operator in `numbers.inject(1, :*)` The `:*` specifies it as a symbol but you could do `numbers.inject(1, '*')` as well. Using a symbol is more idiomatic.